# Why msg.sender has the address of the account which has deployed the contract (and not the one's which interacts with it)?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am currently developing a dapp on ethereum. From what I know msg.sender should has the value of the account who interact with it. However, it keeps the value of the deployer's account.

I am using metamask and solidity ^0.4.24. I am deploying the contact using truffle framework and also Ganache GUI as my virtual node

```
function getMe() public view returns(address){
        return msg.sender;
    }
```

So, I expect this code to return the hash of the account which is interacting with the contract but instead I am taking back the address of the acount which deployed it

Answer (score 0):

`msg.sender` contains the value of the address of the caller. You must be deploying and interacting from the same account, probably using `accounts[0]`.